# What is the meaning of "feed" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> *"If you then examined the European national youth teams that **feed** the World Cup and professional ranks, you would find this strange phenomenon to be even more pronounced."*

Comment: Which definitions have found and which of those have you discounted and why?

Comment: Just as a tributary, a smaller stream, **feeds** or **feeds into** a larger river, those youth teams *supply* players to the professional ranks.

Comment: One of the meanings of **feed**:to give food to a person or an animal.So I think that the youth teams provide players to compete with others in the World Cup.The meaning isn't its basic meaning.I'm not sure if it is correct,so I posted after googling.

Answer (score 1):

Feed in this context means "provide".

So the youth teams provide players for the European leagues.

Example:

"The high schools in our area are of a high level, and **feed** directly into the Ivy League Universities."

Meaning that the Ivy League Universities take many students from the high schools in our area.